# Compile fails when building from source react-native-fcm

Tags: android, react-native, google-cloud-messaging

I've tried all the alternatives that I find on github issues. This looks an version incompatibility problem

`FIRMessagingModule.java:36: error: FIRMessagingModule is not abstract and does not override abstract method onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in ActivityEventListener
public class FIRMessagingModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements LifecycleEventListener, ActivityEventListener {
       ^
AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-fcm\android\src\main\java\com\evollu\react\fcm\FIRMessagingModule.java:274: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-fcm\android\src\main\java\com\evollu\react\fcm\FIRMessagingModule.java:278: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
3 errors
:react-native-fcm:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED`

**React native version:**  1000.0.0 (building from source)
**OS:**  Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing:

(-)compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'

with

(+)compile project(':ReactAndroid')

in node_modules/react-native-fcm/android/build.gradle

Comment: I roll back to compile in the normal way, and I gave a git-upgrade then made the compilation by the origin with my changes and it worked...